# Translate to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I started to rewrite the following code in linq with no avail. Could you help me with this expression please?

```
        bool bReturn = false;
    string[] divs = strExport.Split(chrDivSep);

   // bReturn = divs.Any(D => D.Split(chrItemSep).Any(C => C.Split(chrCoupleSep)[0].ToUpper() == "TABLE"));
    foreach (string strdiv in divs)
    {
        string[] items = strdiv.Split(chrItemSep);
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            string[] couple = item.Split(chrCoupleSep);
            switch (couple[0].ToUpper())
            {
                case "TABLE":
                    // There is a non constant field
                    bReturn = true;
                    break;
            }
            if (bReturn)
                break;

        }
        if (bReturn)
            break;
    }

    return bReturn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (
    from div in strExport.Split(chrDivSep)
    from item in div.Split(chrItemSep)
    where String.Equals(item.Split(chrCoupleSep)[0], "table", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
).Any();
```